# Extract Hyperlink in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have the following question:

I have 2 sheets in Excel. The first one is used to collect all information from sheet 2.
The cells are linked to sheet 2. My problem is that I can't link a hyperlink from sheet2 to a cell from sheet one. It only "extracts" the text.

f.e.
Cell 1 Sheet 2 
Test -> with hyperlink(file:///C:\test.pdf)

Cell 1 Sheet 1
Test

How do I get the hyperlink into sheet1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what Excel help says about hyperlinks:

> Use another cell on the worksheet for
>   the link target To quickly update all
>   formulas in a worksheet that use a
>   HYPERLINK function with the same
>   arguments, you can place the link
>   target in another cell on the same or
>   another worksheet, and then use an
>   absolute reference to that cell as the
>   link_location in the HYPERLINK
>   formulas. Changes that you make to the
>   link target are immediately reflected
>   in the HYPERLINK formulas.
>
> =HYPERLINK($Z$1) In cell Z1, you then enter the path to the link target.

So you could make a link on Cell 1 on Sheet 1 referring to the link that's on Cell 1 Sheet 2

Or try [this solution they mentioned on EE:](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_21426950.html)

> Paste the code below into a module (ALT + F11)
>
> ```
> Function GetAddress(HyperlinkCell As Range)
>     GetAddress = Replace _
>     (HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address,"mailto:", "")
> End Function
> ```
>
> from your worksheet to extract the
>   hyperlink address
>
> ```
> =getaddress(a1)
> ```

Comment: Lol accepted with even an upvote. Ah well, glad it worked for you!

Comment: I think he needs a few more points before he can upvote you.  I did it for him :)  BTW, EE has modified their format so you can't view the responses without being a member.

Comment: @wcm you have to scroll alllll the way down to see the answers ;-)

Comment: Hey Ivo,

I just went back and viewed the web page in IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  

I can't see a solution anywhere. Even all the way down on the bottom.  

Weird!!!

Comment: BTW, don't you think that they should have extended the Cell worksheet function to include Hyperlink as a type.  It shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: They apparently changed the layout @wcm :(